# Uniqueness of backward heat equation on closed manifold with given initial data

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a closed (compact without boundry) Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, do we have uniqueness (assuming solutions exist on $[0,T]$ ) for the backward heat equation

$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial t}+\Delta_gf=0$$
$$f(x,0)=f_0(x),$$
where $f_0$ is some Borel function on $M$.